# I can't pull data with redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to do a simple operation. Below is coinSlice and store.js. I'm trying to pull the data as understood from the code, but when I look at it from developer tools, it shows blank.

```js
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
//import { instanceData } from "../../services/cyriptoApi";
import axios from "axios";

const initialState = {
    coins: [],
    status:null
}

export const getCoins = createAsyncThunk(
    "coins/getCoins", 
    async() => {
    const response = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
    return response?.data
})

const coinSlice = createSlice({
    name:"coin",
    initialState,
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers:{
        [getCoins.pending]: (state, action) => {
            state.status = "pending";
        },
        [getCoins.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            state.status = "fullfilled";
            state.coins = action.payload;
        },
        [getCoins.rejected]: (state, action) => {
            state.status = "rejected";
        }
    }
})

export default coinSlice.reducer;
```

```js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import coinReducer from "./coins/coinSlice";

export default configureStore({
    reducer: {
        coin:coinReducer 
    }
})
```

Comment: how do you invoke `getCoins`?

Comment: I haven't actually called it yet to get it, but shouldn't it look like the state of any development tool?

Comment: getCoins will lead to your data being fetched when you call `dispatch(getCoins())`. It will be in your state after that, not before.

Comment: Ah. I understood thank you :)